# PayPal recurring payment plan modification

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I have a **PayPal** billing plan for recurring payments. But I need to achieve a scenario where if a user subscribes to my billing plan in the middle of a month then he will be charged instantly and the next billing date will be the first day of next month. How this scenario can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

What type of billing plan for what type of recurring payments? There's like 5+ different APIs and versions.

With the the newest [Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#3-create-a-plan), you could have a plan that charges a setup fee for your instant charge:

```
  "payment_preferences": {
    "setup_fee": {
      "value": "10",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
```

and in billing cycles has a `"tenure_type": "TRIAL"` with no pricing_scheme that lasts XX amount of days, where XX is calculated by you to be the number of days remaining in the current month that you don't want to charge.  Then after the initial XX day trial there would be a `"tenure_type": "REGULAR"` for charging every month.